# Roots of quadratic equation

Tags: roots, quadratics

If the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, express $\frac1\alpha-\frac1\beta$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

I know how to express $\alpha+\beta$ or $\alpha\beta$ which is usually enough, but this question requires $\alpha-\beta$ to solve it. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\alpha - \beta =\pm \sqrt{(\alpha+\beta)^2 - 4\alpha \beta}$

Comment: What you wrote is $\lvert\alpha-\beta\rvert$.

Comment: @Bernard thanks I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks, but I suppose I need to write some sort of justification as to how you got this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the roots of the polynomial from the quadratic equation, so you have your alpha and beta

Comment: This will work here but then you are not using the full potential of symmetric polynomials which is the real intent of the problem.